# IOError (closed stream) on ActiveStorage::Attached::One#attach (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to duplicate an attached file, using the new [Rails 6 syntax for downloading files](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files)

```rb
if original.attachment.attached?
  original.attachment.open do |tempfile|
    clone.attachment.attach({
      io: tempfile,
      filename: original.attachment.blob.filename,
      content_type: original.attachment.blob.content_type
    })
  end
end
```

And I get this error: `IOError (closed stream)`

If I check the /tmp/ folder during execution the tempfile copy is there. I don't know why is this error being raised.

I'm running Rails 6.0.0 and ruby 2.6.5p114 on macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. In rails 6 you have to open the tempfile again, when attaching, like this:

`io: File.open(tempfile.path),`

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Thank you! Was really confused why this wasn't working after an upgrade to Rails 6